# ModuleLoadError on org.javassist on Wildfly 28

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-28

I'm trying to upgrade Wildfly from 26 to 28 (had to skip 27 due to some irreconcilable hibernate bug). I'm using Wildfly with Infinispan-module from https://infinispan.org/download/. However it depends on module "org.javassist" which gives me this error summary:

```
2023-10-26 13:49:04,883 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "xxxxxear-7.150.0-SNAPSHOT.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xxxxxear-7.150.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"xxxxxejb-7.150.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\".component.Startup.START" => "java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    Caused by: jakarta.ejb.EJBException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void com.yyyyyyyy.xxxxx.server.cache.infinispan.InfinispanCacheProvider.postConstruct() on com.yyyyyyyy.xxxxx.server.cache.infinispan.InfinispanCacheProvider@71c39eba
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void com.yyyyyyyy.xxxxx.server.cache.infinispan.InfinispanCacheProvider.postConstruct() on com.yyyyyyyy.xxxxx.server.cache.infinispan.InfinispanCacheProvider@71c39eba
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: org.javassist"}}
```

The full stack looks like this:

```
2023-10-26 13:49:04,682 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 93) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."xxxxxear-7.150.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."xxxxxejb-7.150.0-SNAPSHOT.jar".component.Startup.START: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."xxxxxear-7.150.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."xxxxxejb-7.150.0-SNAPSHOT.jar".component.Startup.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
        at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:57)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
        at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:170)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:141)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:127)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:141)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:54)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: jakarta.ejb.EJBException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void com.yyyyyyyy.xxxxx.server.cache.infinispan.InfinispanCacheProvider.postConstruct() on com.yyyyyyyy.xxxxx.server.cache.infinispan.InfinispanCacheProvider@71c39eba
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:268)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:416)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:68)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.weld@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.java:43)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.StartupCountDownInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupCountDownInterceptor.java:25)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:168)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void com.yyyyyyyy.xxxxx.server.cache.infinispan.InfinispanCacheProvider.postConstruct() on com.yyyyyyyy.xxxxx.server.cache.infinispan.InfinispanCacheProvider@71c39eba
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:85)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:66)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:122)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:174)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$ApplicationScopedContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:140)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:102)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:131)
        at deployment.xxxxxear-7.150.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.xxxxxejb-7.150.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//com.yyyyyyyy.xxxxx.server.cache.infinispan.InfinispanCacheProvider$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getCache(Unknown Source)
        at deployment.xxxxxear-7.150.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.xxxxxejb-7.150.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//com.yyyyyyyy.xxxxx.server.cache.CacheProducer.getCache(CacheProducer.java:30)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:85)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ProducerMethodProducer.produce(ProducerMethodProducer.java:103)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractMemberProducer.produce(AbstractMemberProducer.java:161)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:180)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.contexts.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:64)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:680)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:780)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:345)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:356)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:69)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:71)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:117)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:161)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.contexts.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:64)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:680)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:780)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.ParameterInjectionPointImpl.getValueToInject(ParameterInjectionPointImpl.java:76)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.getParameterValues(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:150)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:75)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractInstantiator.newInstance(AbstractInstantiator.java:28)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.produce(BasicInjectionTarget.java:112)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.produce(BeanInjectionTarget.java:186)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:160)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.contexts.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:64)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:680)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:780)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.ParameterInjectionPointImpl.getValueToInject(ParameterInjectionPointImpl.java:76)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.getParameterValues(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:150)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:75)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractInstantiator.newInstance(AbstractInstantiator.java:28)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.produce(BasicInjectionTarget.java:112)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.produce(BeanInjectionTarget.java:186)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:160)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.contexts.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:64)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:680)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:780)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:345)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:356)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:71)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:73)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.DynamicInjectionPointInjector.inject(DynamicInjectionPointInjector.java:61)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInjectionTarget.inject(SessionBeanInjectionTarget.java:138)
        at org.jboss.as.weld@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContext.inject(WeldInjectionContext.java:39)
        at org.jboss.as.weld@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionInterceptor.java:51)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:28)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.weld@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.weld@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.java:111)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
        at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:254)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:83)
        ... 110 more
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: org.javassist
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1271)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1627)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPaths(Module.java:1588)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPathsUnchecked(Module.java:1611)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:760)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:350)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:765)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1217)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1228)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393)
        at org.infinispan.commons:ispn-9.4@9.4.16.Final//org.infinispan.commons.util.ServiceFinder.addServices(ServiceFinder.java:61)
        at org.infinispan.commons:ispn-9.4@9.4.16.Final//org.infinispan.commons.util.ServiceFinder.load(ServiceFinder.java:44)
        at org.infinispan.core:ispn-9.4@9.4.16.Final//org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.<init>(ParserRegistry.java:73)
        at org.infinispan.core:ispn-9.4@9.4.16.Final//org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.<init>(ParserRegistry.java:67)
        at org.infinispan.core:ispn-9.4@9.4.16.Final//org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.<init>(ParserRegistry.java:63)
        at org.infinispan.core:ispn-9.4@9.4.16.Final//org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:318)
        at org.infinispan.core:ispn-9.4@9.4.16.Final//org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:293)
        at org.infinispan.core:ispn-9.4@9.4.16.Final//org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:281)
        at deployment.xxxxxear-7.150.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.xxxxxejb-7.150.0-SNAPSHOT.jar//com.yyyyyyyy.xxxxx.server.cache.infinispan.InfinispanCacheProvider.postConstruct(InfinispanCacheProvider.java:40)
        ... 115 more
```

It seems that the same module is depended from built-in modules as well. But it seems it's only the added infinispan-module that have problems.

**Update**

I was able to progress on the module problem only to progress to new problems. To make a long story short:

| Problem v Module > | Built-in | Infinispan 9.4.16 | Infinispan 14.0.19 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Relevancy | For internal use | - | - |
| Missing module `org.javassist` | - | Was able to add jar and `module.xml` as wildfly modules at `system/layers/base/org/javassist/3.27.0-GA` | Doesn't seem to be dependency any more |
| Not upgraded to jakartaee 10 | - | Converted with [Eclipse Transformer](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.transformer) only to discover at it keeps metadata in a serialized .dat file. | Converted with Eclipse Transformer |
| Next problem | - | - | - |

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use an extremely old version (9.4.x) of Infinispan's WildFly module with WF28.  Try using a more recent version.

Comment: I aware of that yes, but we're stuck with in for now (work is underway). I actual made some progress; see update.